# Basic Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a slideshow in JavaScript and jQuery to show an array of images.

My idea is to put 3 divs on the page:

- One with a left button
- one with a right button
- one called screen that will display the image.

This is the code I have written, but I don't know what's missing. Maybe an `onload` event?

```
var now =0;
var image_array= 
[
    "../cabinets/001.jpg",
    "../cabinets/002.jpg",
    "../cabinets/003.jpg"
];
$("#left").click(left(  if(now<image_array.length)
    {
        now++;
        $('#screen').css('background-image', 'url("' + array[now] + '")');
    }));
$("#right").click(  if(now>0)
    {
        now--;
        $('#screen').css('background-image', 'url("' + array[now] + '")');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code, here is result:

**1)** have you included jQuery library into your project?

**2)** in your jQuery code in lines:

```
$('#screen').css('background-image', 'url("' + array[now] + '")');
```

you using bad array name `array[now]`, your array is `image_array`, so you must rewrite this into `image_array[now]`

**3)** your definition of `.click` function is not correct. You must define it as: `.click(function(){ ... });`, so your lines will look like:

```
// left click
$("#left").click(function(){
    if(now > 0){            
        now--;
    }
    $('#screen').css('background-image', 'url("' + image_array[now] + '")');alert(now);
});
```

and

```
// right click
$("#right").click(function(){
    if(now < image_array.length-1){
        now++;
    }
    $('#screen').css('background-image', 'url("' + image_array[now] + '")');alert(now);
});
```

Here is working JSFiddle solution: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6X3d/)**

Here is the second solution with updated IF terms: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6X3d/1/)**